# Unable to get JSON data after a word is match with (regex )

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the data for `Total Cash Dividends Paid` and it returns `<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f3b92110988>`. https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/ASJT.JK/financials/income-annual

I have put the output of `reu2` in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0LADUI/1).

```
import requests, re
from lxml import html

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) '
                  'AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'
}
page_reu2 = requests.get(
    'https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/ASJT.JK/financials/income-annual',
    headers=headers)
reu2 = html.fromstring(page_reu2.content)
reu2 = reu2.xpath('//*[@id="fusion-metadata"]/text()')[0]
print (re.search(r"\bTotal Cash Dividends Paid\b", reu2))
```

The desired result supposed to get:

```
[{"date":"2021-12-31","value":"-146.816000"},
 {"date":"2020-12-31","value":"-250.130000"},
 {"date":"2019-12-31","value":"-200.232000"},
 {"date":"2018-12-31","value":"-250.130000"},
 {"date":"2017-12-31","value":"-101.075000"},
 {"date":"2016-12-31","value":"-75.487000"}]

[{"date":"2022-03-31","value":"-350.000000"},
 {"date":"2021-12-31","value":"-146.816000"},
 {"date":"2021-09-30","value":"-146.816000"},
 {"date":"2021-06-30","value":"-146.816000"},
 {"date":"2021-03-31","value":"0.000000"}]
```

There are two set of data which the first one is annual data and the second is interim/quarterly data. Would appreciate if there is an explanation of the answer.

Comment: To make it easier for us to help, you want to make a MVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  If the issue is with the regex, get the string `rue2` and put it in the question, we don't care about the request steps.  The more you make your question a copy/paste for us to run, the sooner you'll get the help you want :)

Comment: Please, read [*Regular Expression HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) article and documentation of [*`re.search()`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [*Match Objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Comment: See also [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42604800/how-to-convert-sre-sre-match-type-to-string-and-integer) that shows how to `re.findall` or using BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML.

Comment: @hc_dev edited with import module. Also a output of `reu2` is in https://regex101.com/r/0LADUI/1

Comment: You won't get that data by trying to scrape the URL you are calling as the response does not contain script tag you are then trying to scrape. Reuters is a JS heavily site with lots of deferred async calls. You need to find the actual resource that returns the data or use a tool that have a JS support so you can then query the final compiled page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your regex you can see the details here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0LADUI/2).

we follow the same concept as the last time but here there are multiple matches.

so we wont use `re.search` we will use `re.findall()` instead to get us the matches values directly, we won't have to use `.group(1)` like the last time.

we use `eval` here to convert the string into list.

```py
import requests, re
from lxml import html

# page = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/AALI.JK/key-metrics/per-share-data')
page = requests.get('https://www.reuters.com/markets/companies/ASJT.JK/financials/income-annual')

data = html.fromstring(page.content)

txt = data.xpath('//*[@id="fusion-metadata"]/text()')[0]

# eps_norm_annual = float(re.search('"eps_normalized_annual":"([0-9.]+)"', txt).group(1))
data = [eval(match) for match in  re.findall('"Total Cash Dividends Paid","items":(\[.+?\])', txt)]
```

Comment: How about `re.findall('Total Cash Dividends Paid",\"items\":\[([":0-9-,a-z.}{]*)]',txt)` in your opinion? Perhaps you can elaborate a bit of your solution?

Comment: @behappy I'm not good at explaining how regular expressions work, but the main concept of my pattern is to find the list that comes directly after the "Total..." which is in square brackets i also added "?" To make it greedy.